# Wordpress - Export Featured Image mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm working on a news site that has content since 2001, and I'd like to get all posts and their featured images. However, it has a quirk, I need to have the posts and their images in the database without having to download them because they are in a blob.

How do I get this result?
Should I manually copy from the database?
Is there any change I have to make?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do the current website in wordpress, I recommend
to create contents in wordpress way only. These steps can be followed.

1. Download the old website to your local environment where the new website is developing.
2. Connect to the old website db from wordpress using [wpdb](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database)
3. Query the required contents from the old website to WordPress.
4. Create posts/pages with contents with [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)
5. You can convert the blob to file with the below function and save it to a temporary location `file_put_contents('/path/to/new/file_name', $my_blob);`
6. Upload the file using [wp_handle_upload](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload)
7. Set it as the featured image using [wp_insert_attachment](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)

This can be executed in a loop depending upon your requirement.

Comment: I'm working with very heavy files, and would not like to download them. I would like to keep as the same, no bank, so where without having to download the images and files

Comment: Then probabbly you will have to keep it in a seprate table and refer the post id there. But you are breaking the wordpress structure and no wp functions can be used for getting or updating those datas.  When we use a framework we must use it's own way for storing/retreving data.